# Cómo permir en cloud firestore interactuar solo usuarios logueados exceptuando la autenticación

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Mi código de reglas es el siguiente:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

mi problema es cuando quiero crear un usuario nuevo, no me deja porque me pide estar logueado, que es lógico porque es lo que estoy haciendo, pero no se cómo exceptuar ciertas funciones.

Answer (score 0):

en ese caso es cierto mientras no estes logeado no vas a poder escribir en la colección, yo tengo dos opciones, la una es que una vez que creas el nuevo usuario o este se registra aplica la función "createUserWithEmailAndPassword" una vez que se haya completado con éxito esto, logealo automáticamente con "signInWithEmailAndPassword" y de ahí guardas en la colección y ay debería dejarte ya que ya estas logeado. Otra opción podría ser poner en las reglas de tu firestore que dentro de la colección usuarios(por ejemplo) cualquiera pueda escribir... pero solo en esa colección